# Beautiful Soup how to check any of multiple attributes exists with find_all?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to find all "a" tags that have either "href" and/or "data-href" as attribute.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
soup.find_all("a", href=True) + soup.find_all("a", {"data-href": True})
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this in one find_all?
Thanks

Comment: Check this - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function

Answer (score 1):

If you have **BS4 4.7.1** or above you can use following `css selector`.

```
for item in soup.select('a[href],a[data-href],a[href][data-href]'):
    print(item)
```

Let's take this example.

```
data='''<a href="/pqr/abc" > Hello</a>
<a data-href="/xyz/abc" >World </a>
<a href="/hello/abc" data-href="/world/abc" > Hello World </a>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

for item in soup.select('a[href],a[data-href],a[href][data-href]'):
    print(item)
```

**Output**:

```
<a href="/pqr/abc"> Hello</a>
<a data-href="/xyz/abc">World </a>
<a data-href="/world/abc" href="/hello/abc"> Hello World </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In BeautifulSoup 4.7.1 these CSS selectors can be used: `a[href]`, `a[data-href]` and `a[href][data-href]`. Use the same code as @KunduK's code as he pointed out.
If you are using versions older than 4.7.1 you have to do your code:

```
soup.find_all("a", href=True) + soup.find_all("a", {"data-href": True})
```